# oktaAuth with react stuck in login/callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, okta

I am using

```
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^5.8.0",
"@okta/okta-react": "^6.3.0",
```

in my react app.
This is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppWithRouterAccess from './AppWithRouterAccess';
import history from './data/history';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <AppWithRouterAccess />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

(history is just `export default createBrowserHistory();`

AppWithRouterAccess.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, withRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, SecureRoute, LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { OktaAuth, toRelativeUrl } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import './App.css'
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Enrichment from './pages/Enrichment';
import PrePublish from './pages/PrePublish';
import Published from './pages/Published';
import CheckPublication from './pages/CheckPublication';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import history from './data/history';
const OktaCred = require('./data/idc_cred.json')

export default withRouter(class AppWithRouterAccess extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            is_logged: false
        }
        this.onAuthRequired = this.onAuthRequired.bind(this);
        this.oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
            clientId: OktaCred.clientId,
            issuer: OktaCred.issuer,
            redirectUri: OktaCred.redirectUri,
            scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
            postLogoutRedirectUr: OktaCred.postLogoutRedirectUri
        });
    }

    onAuthRequired = () => {
        history.push('/login');
    }

    restoreOriginalUri = async(_oktaAuth, originalUri) => {
        history.replace(toRelativeUrl(originalUri, window.location.origin));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
            {this.state.is_logged?
            <NavBar/>:undefined}
            <Security oktaAuth={this.oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={this.restoreOriginalUri}>
                <Switch>
                    <SecureRoute path='/' exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/login' render={()=><SignIn />} />
                    <Route path='/login/callback' component={LoginCallback} />
                </Switch>
            </Security>
            </>
        );
    }
});
```

idc_cred.json is a JSON file with all the Okta credentials (tested and works!)

SignIn.jsx is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignInForm from '../components/SignInForm.jsx';
import { withOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';

export default withOktaAuth(class SignIn extends Component {

  render() {
    if (!this.props.authState) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return this.props.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated ?
      <Redirect to="/"/> :
      <SignInForm />;
  }
});
```

and finally, SignInForm.jsx is:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './styles/SignInForm.css';
import { withOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react'
import Logo from '../assets/Jfrog-Logo.svg'

export default withOktaAuth( class SignInForm extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            sessionToken: null,
            username: '',
            password: '',
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state)
        this.props.oktaAuth.signInWithCredentials({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(transaction => {
            var pushFactor = transaction.factors.find(function(factor) {
                return factor.provider === 'OKTA' && factor.factorType === 'push';
            });
              
            pushFactor.verify({
                autoPush: true
            })
            console.log(transaction)
            if(transaction.sessionToken){
                this.setState(
                { sessionToken: transaction.sessionToken },
                () => {
                    this.props.oktaAuth.signInWithRedicred({sessionToken: transaction.sessionToken})
                }
                )
            }
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('Found an error', err));
        
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({username: e.target.value});
    }
    
    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        if (this.state.sessionToken) {
            return null;
        }
        return(      
            <div className="login-container">
                <div className="total-login">
                    <div className="logo-login">
                        <img src={Logo} alt="logo" className="logo-self-login"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-form-main">
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <p className="login-title">Login with Okta</p>
                            <label>
                            <p className="login-sub-title">Username:</p>
                            <input className="login-input" id="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                            <p className="login-sub-title">Password:</p>
                            <input id="password" type="password" className="login-input" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
                            </label>
                            <br/>
                            <button className="login-button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
                            <div/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
})
```

When the user enters his creds, the page becomes a blank page with Loading..., like so:
[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks!

The network tab:

[image]

Comment: what do you see in the network tab? which requests are sent to Okta? that'd help to understand a bit

Comment: also is `Loading...` a part of your `Home`? Also what is your `redirectUri`, which is taken from `OktaCreds`?

Comment: and I believe that might be your problem `this.props.oktaAuth.signInWithRedicred` in your code. It has to be `signInWithRedirect`

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev, thanks for the response,
The Loading... is in the SignIn.jsx page (when props.authState is null),
the edirectUri is https://*****/login/callback where the url is set with NGinx.
and I've changed the signInWithRedicred and still nothing...
I am posting the network tab in the question body

Comment: can you capture traffic starting with the first hit of your app, if possible?